# Raspberry pi can't find read property of ble periphral device

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

BLE code was written using the Blake module as Python3 in Raspberry Pi4 (master).

Of the read, write, write with no response, notify attributes of the discovered device, only the read property does not appear. enter image description here

Below is code of raspberry pi

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

address = "D8:43:6B:54:D5:AC" # peripheral mac address

async def run(address):    
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        print('connected')
        services = await client.get_services()        
        for service in services:
            print('\tservice: ', service)    
            print('\tuuid:', service.uuid)
            print('\tcharacteristic list:')
            for characteristic in service.characteristics:
                print('\t\t', characteristic)
                print('\t\tuuid:', characteristic.uuid)
                print('\t\tdescription :', characteristic.description)
                `print('\t\tproperties :', characteristic.properties, "\n")

    print('disconnect')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run(address))
print('done')
```

But when I ran the same code on Windows, I could find it all. I want to get read property from raspberry pi.

what shoud I do?

Comment: What happens when you run it on raspberry pi? Errors, warnings?

Comment: It works fine, but I can't see the read attribute.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed what is printed out from your script. Also, have you looked at the peripheral device using a Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? Does that show the read attribute?